# How to make a `ListTile` leading being tall enough to contain column of widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I don't find a fix to my issue. I have setup a [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c4deff213c14e00ed33cddc3656e4d02) for demonstrate it.

The leading is attached to a large icon which overflows vertically.

What I am trying to do is to have a ListTile inside a container with a given height to place the large icon.

The leading holds a Column that serves as a vertical centerer for a multiline widget collection.

The first row exposes the overflow.

The second row only has the icon and exposes no issue.

My code is as follows:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children:[
      
      Container(
        color:Colors.red,
        height:200,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children:[
            Icon(Icons.abc, size:180),
            Text("More actions"),
          ]),
          title: Text('Hello, World!'),
          trailing:ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){}, child:Text("CONNECT"),),  
        ),
      ),
      
        
        
      Container(
        color:Colors.blue,
        height:200,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.abc, size:180),        
          title: Text('Hello, World!'),
          trailing: ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){}, child:Text("CONNECT"),),
        ),
      ),
      
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that ListTile was design with the material specification that already have a definition for the heigh of the icons.
The leading widget is not meant to be so big, this is taken from ListTile implementation code:

```
final BoxConstraints maxIconHeightConstraint = BoxConstraints(
  // One-line trailing and leading widget heights do not follow
  // Material specifications, but this sizing is required to adhere
  // to accessibility requirements for smallest tappable widget.
  // Two- and three-line trailing widget heights are constrained
  // properly according to the Material spec.
  maxHeight: (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + densityAdjustment.dy,
);
```

You can search in listTile source code docs that have a lot of info.

On the other hand, your second ListTile, despite that not pressent any overflow wont look good either, you can try to update the size of the icon and you'll check that the title start loosing and the tile looks wired. So its a kind of bug and i recommend you to avoid it.
Example:

```
  Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    height: 200,
    child: ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.abc, size: 300),
      title: const Text('Hello, World!'),
      trailing: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text("CONNECT"),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

With that said, i suggest you to make a custom widget with a layout that serve your needs and doesn't have the material constraint using rows and columns.

Hope it helps!